# Using fabric8's KubernetesClient, how do I construct a URL to a particular Kubernetes resource?

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

I'd like to do the Java equivalent of the Kubernetes Go client's ability to create a URL to a resource without having to manually construct it.

In Go, using [Kubernetes' `client-go/rest/client.go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/rest/client.go), it's something like this:

```
u := client.Post()
  .Resource("pods")
  .Namespace("fred")
  .Name("podname")
  .URL()
```

(Note: I am no kind of Go programmer.)

I don't see anything in the [undocumented `KubernetesClient` interface](https://static.javadoc.io/io.fabric8/kubernetes-client/2.3.1/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/KubernetesClient.html) that would let me do the equivalent.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can do something like this:

```
final DefaultKubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
final NonNamespaceOperation<Pod, PodList, DoneablePod, PodResource<Pod, DoneablePod>> foo = client.pods().inNamespace("kube-system");
  assert foo instanceof OperationSupport;
  final URL url = ((OperationSupport)foo).getNamespacedUrl();
```

Obviously this isn't great from a super-clean perspective (the return value of `pods()` is an `OperationSupport` only because of the way it's implemented, not by contract) but it is a way to do it.